# background image about one point short

Tags: ios, objective-c

Forgive me if there is another answer for this question, but I haven't been able to figure out a good way to search for the problem.

On the iPhone5 simulator my background images are about a point short, despite being the proper size. See screenshot:

[image]

My images are all 640px × 1136px .png files, and my image code is below:

```
backgroundImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [backgroundImage1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [backgroundImage1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [self addSubview:backgroundImage1];
```

I would try it on my phone, but my certificate is expired, so I can't until the dev center comes back online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
[backgroundImage1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

to

```
 [backgroundImage1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

so that it fills the entire screen

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! That fills the image to the bottom of the menu bar instead of to the top of the screen. I've also tried UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, which leaves a border around the background image.

Comment: Whatever, you got me on the right track. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I added an answer with what I ended up actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
frame.origin.y -= 10.0f;
frame.size.height += 20.0f;
```

This filled the screen and under the status bar. I had to adjust some positioning of other things on the page, but it worked. Other better answers are more than welcome! Or just an explanation of what's going on.